Is it good SEO to meta refresh / JavaScript an error page to my homepage?
At present my website has out of service URLs after migrating from Wordpress. Google's report sees those pages.
Is it bad, neutral, or good for Google's purposes to have, say, a 404 page with a meta refresh and/or JavaScript redirect to the website's homepage? I have seen this done with one educational site I worked on.
Thanks,

If the content still exists as pages on the new site, 301 redirect them to the new URL rather than throw a 404.  That way any backlinks will still carry value, and users won't hit a 404 page whilst the page still exists in the SERPs.
If the pages do not exist on the new site, then javascript redirects on the 404 page are unlikely to be anything but neutral.  I can see no reason for Google to render the content of a 404 page, as all they are going to be interested in is whether to remove it from their index.
As always with SEO advice, only Google know for sure, but I can't think of a single reason it would be good or bad for SEO, as long as the status is appropriate.
Ultimately, users should not be hitting 404 pages after the site has been re-indexed.  If they still are, I'd look into where they are coming from, as a good lost backlink should probably also be 301d, both for SEO and UX.
